# Difference between pointer and array as template arguments

Tags: c++, pointers, templates

```
template<typename T, typename U = int>
struct A {};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct A<T*, U> {};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct A<T[], U> {};

int main()
{
    A<int*> m; // m: A<int*, int>
    A<int[]> n; // n: A<int[], int>

    return 0;
}
```

What's the difference between `int[]` and `int*` here as template arguments? Isn't `int[]` simply a pointer too?

Comment: Arrays are not pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Isn't `int[]` simply a pointer too?

No, it simply isn't. Arrays are arrays and pointers are pointers. Arrays are not pointers and pointers are not arrays. `int[]` is an array.

There is a case where "array is pointer (and isn't an array)": In a function parameter delcaration, an array parameter will be adjusted to be a pointer to element of that array type. Such adjustment doesn't apply to other contexts. Template arguments are a separate context from function arguments and in that context the mentioned adjustment does not occur.

> What's the difference between `int[]` and `int*` here as template arguments?

The difference is that in one case the type argument is an array, and in the other case the type argument is a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, these are different types. You can tell because these do different things:

```
const char* a = "hi";
const char[] b = "hi";
```

The first allocates a pointer on the stack (and the literal probably somewhere else), the second allocates the whole literal on the stack as an array. Therefore, although they are implicitly convertible into each other, they are different types.